# Problems with sending email to Jenkins localhost

Tags: email, testing, jenkins, deployment, devops

I'm learning the nuts and bolts of using the Jenkins automated server at work for our DevOps tasks. Currently, users can't send request emails to localhost unless they log in as localhost-- essentially, they have to send an email to themselves when logged in as localhost, or else the email will bounce back. What is a better way to configure this mail client?

(Caveat: I didn't set up the email client, but I'm trying to learn more about Jenkins so I can do a better job with it than the employee who was previously in charge of it.)

I'm all ears to any advice that's offered!

Comment: Could you elaborate plz? I'm not sure I understand correctly. What do you mean by this? >> Currently, users can't send request emails to localhost unless they log in as localhost-- essentially, they have to send an email to themselves when logged in as localhost, or else the email will bounce back.

Comment: One of Jenkins' features is to read emails sent to the admin account, and then once the email is parsed, it runs a script or activates a trigger. Currently, no one outside of the local server can send an email to Jenkins unless they are logged into Jenkins as the admin. What could I be doing differently here? I'm happy to provide screenshots for further clarification if you need. Thanks!